# jquery keyup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, when I add a class to various inputs (after a user presses submit), this function does not record keypresses being made within those inputs. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong as I've tried `$('incomplete_required').keyup(){}` and what is below, as it seems `.on()` is more modern..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.incomplete_required').on("keyup", function(){
        console.log('keyed');
    });
});
```

What have I done wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: did you consider using .bind() instead of on() , because on() is used for attaching event listeners, and looks like you are trying to trigger a function on keyup event.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are dynamically changing elements in the dom - it is best to delegate the event to an existing parent in the dom

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("keyup",'.incomplete_required', function(){
        console.log('keyed');
    });
});
```

Obviously replacing `body` with the closest parent element that exists on dom ready

By delegating - the event will bubble up to the "parent" element - which is where the event is handled

Comment: +1 I didn't refresh the page not realising you already posted that. Lets hope it fixes the issue for OP as the requirement for dynamic bindings was my suspicion as well.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl yeah that always happens to me too :)  I'm sure this is the reason why it's not working

Comment: yes! works perfectly. thanks! I thought the idea of `on()` was that it "took care" of dynamically generated content

Comment: @thomas: `live` used to do that by automacially bubbling up to the document. `on()`, as of 1.7.2, is the preferred method of attaching and removing events. Ii provides several overrides allowing you to bind statically or dynamically. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

Seeing this works before the submit I think you are loosing the event bindings as the elements are re-rendered but the document ready event is not firing again.

A dynamic binding solution may be required here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '.incomplete_required', function(){
        console.log('keyed');
    });
});​
```

Mind you, `document` is very far up so the closest static element will be better off course.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the "keypress" event instead.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/RRgvU/

Comment: Can you explain why to use this instead of `keyup`?

Comment: keypress is a different event than keyup, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. While this may work in his case, they are not the same thing.